# Nested Columns height issue Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, nested, bootstrap-5

I am having issues with the height of my nested columns.
I want the columns to be equal height both on big screens and on small screens. But at the moment the size is perfect at the biggest and smallest viewports but not at the medium viewports.
Please see examples in codepen:
Example of how I would like the columns to behave: https://codepen.io/marawa/pen/rNyRLyZ

[image]
Example of how they behave at the moment (check responsiveness on example): https://codepen.io/marawa/pen/xxqBOde
[[image]

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row rad1 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-5 col1">
      <h2 class="text-center">Vasketips</h2></br>
      <p>Diamondcare er en keramisk coating. Det vil si en type flytende glass som legges på lakken.  For å få full effekt krever denne en viss herdetid. Full herdetid regnes å være 72 timer fra  tidspunktet for påføring. For at både du og bilen skal ha mest mulig nytte og effekt av  Diamondcare Keramisk Lakkbeskyttelse kommer vi med noen vasketips:</p>
    </br>

    <ul class="fa-ul">
      <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Etter den første uken står du fritt til å vaske bilen på vanlig måte. Vi anbefaler  bilrelaterte vaskeprodukter – ikke Zalo eller parafin/diesel. Før såpevask kan du trygt  bruke petrokjemisk avfetting til å fjerne den plagsomme trafikkfilmen som oppstår  (spesielt på vinterhalvåret).</li>
      </br>
        <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Vi kommer gjerne med anbefalinger av vaskeprodukter. Dersom du setter bort vasken  til andre bør du informere om at du har lakkbeskyttelse på bilen. </li>
      </br>
        <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Ved å benytte Diamondcare Refresher på bilen ca. hver 4-6 mnd. Vil dette gjøre at lakken oppfører seg som da bilen var ny-behandlet. Garantien opprettholdes selv uten  bruk av dette produktet. </li>
      </br>
        <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Tørk bilen for å holde den lenger ren. Vi anbefaler at du bruker det medfølgende blå  mikrofiber-tørkehåndkleet etter at bilen er ferdig vasker og spylt over. Fukt- og vri det  opp før du begynner å tørke. Da tiltrekker det seg mest mulig. </li>
      </br>
        <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Rebehandling er ikke nødvendig for å opprettholde garantien, men det kan utføres om  ønskelig. Ta kontakt med din forhandler for nærmere informasjon om dette. </li>
    </ul>
      

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col2">
      <div class="row rad2 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col3">
           <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
            <iframe
              src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?fbclid=IwAR2KcXLf_v8knVxaJzKdD7WpLzJGrdrqd1pG_kbzB5arEKpRkKPSNvTh9h4&v=HVp1321oon8&feature=youtu.be"
              allowfullscreen
            ></iframe>
          </div>
        </div><!--end of col3-->

        <div class="col-12 col4">
                          <h4>Har du spørsmål?</h4>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">E-post</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Din e-post">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label" placeholder="Skriv ditt spørsmål her...">Spørsmål</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>  
            <div class="mb-3">  
            <input class="btn btn-custom" type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </div><!--end of col4-->

      </div><!--end of rad2-->
    </div><!--end of col2-->
  </div><!--end of rad1-->
</div><!--end of container-fluid-->
```

I need the columns to be equal height in all viewports until it collapses for the smaller viewports. If that can't be done then I need it to go straight from full size to collapsed when it goes from full size to medium size.

I suspect the reason for the difference in height is because the video and form I added have their own bootstrap code for placement, margin, padding etc.? Anyways I have read the Bootstrap 5 material available and tried to remedy the problem for days without effect, so thought somebody here might have the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap, the columns are normally the same height, but on your right-hand column, you have a row, which will only expand to the height of its children unless you tell it different (add `h-100`).

Adding `h-100` to the row will make the two `col-12` columns fill the column space equally.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {

        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    /* change the background color */
    .navbar-custom {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }

    /* CSS only for examples not required for centering */
    .container {
        height: 100%;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .col1 {
        background-color: #82d4f5;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .col3 {
        background-color: #edc324;
        margin-bottom: 15px;

    }

    .col4 {
        background-color: #8e7cc3;

    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row rad1 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-5 col1">
            <h2 class="text-center">Vasketips</h2></br>
            <p>Diamondcare er en keramisk coating. Det vil si en type flytende glass som legges på lakken. For å få full effekt krever denne en viss herdetid. Full herdetid regnes å være 72 timer fra tidspunktet for påføring. For at både du og bilen skal ha mest mulig nytte og effekt av Diamondcare Keramisk Lakkbeskyttelse kommer vi med noen vasketips:</p>
            </br>

            <ul class="fa-ul">
                <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Etter den første uken står du fritt til å vaske bilen på vanlig måte. Vi anbefaler bilrelaterte vaskeprodukter – ikke Zalo eller parafin/diesel. Før såpevask kan du trygt bruke petrokjemisk avfetting til å fjerne den plagsomme trafikkfilmen som oppstår (spesielt på vinterhalvåret).</li>
                </br>
                <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Vi kommer gjerne med anbefalinger av vaskeprodukter. Dersom du setter bort vasken til andre bør du informere om at du har lakkbeskyttelse på bilen. </li>
                </br>
                <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Ved å benytte Diamondcare Refresher på bilen ca. hver 4-6 mnd. Vil dette gjøre at lakken oppfører seg som da bilen var ny-behandlet. Garantien opprettholdes selv uten bruk av dette produktet. </li>
                </br>
                <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Tørk bilen for å holde den lenger ren. Vi anbefaler at du bruker det medfølgende blå mikrofiber-tørkehåndkleet etter at bilen er ferdig vasker og spylt over. Fukt- og vri det opp før du begynner å tørke. Da tiltrekker det seg mest mulig. </li>
                </br>
                <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Rebehandling er ikke nødvendig for å opprettholde garantien, men det kan utføres om ønskelig. Ta kontakt med din forhandler for nærmere informasjon om dette. </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col2">
            <div class="row rad2 h-100">
                <div class="col-12 col3">
                    <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
                        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?fbclid=IwAR2KcXLf_v8knVxaJzKdD7WpLzJGrdrqd1pG_kbzB5arEKpRkKPSNvTh9h4&v=HVp1321oon8&feature=youtu.be" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end of col3-->

                <div class="col-12 col4">
                    <h4>Har du spørsmål?</h4>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">E-post</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Din e-post">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label" placeholder="Skriv ditt spørsmål her...">Spørsmål</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input class="btn btn-custom" type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end of col4-->

            </div>
            <!--end of rad2-->
        </div>
        <!--end of col2-->
    </div>
    <!--end of rad1-->
</div>
<!--end of container-fluid-->
```

If you want the video to have its own space and the form directly below the video, you can make the row flex direction as column and have the form column expand to fill the space using flex-grow.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {

        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    /* change the background color */
    .navbar-custom {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }

    /* CSS only for examples not required for centering */
    .container {
        height: 100%;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .col1 {
        background-color: #82d4f5;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .col3 {
        background-color: #edc324;
        margin-bottom: 15px;

    }

    .col4 {
        background-color: #8e7cc3;

    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row rad1 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-5 col1">
            <h2 class="text-center">Vasketips</h2></br>
            <p>Diamondcare er en keramisk coating. Det vil si en type flytende glass som legges på lakken. For å få full effekt krever denne en viss herdetid. Full herdetid regnes å være 72 timer fra tidspunktet for påføring. For at både du og bilen skal ha mest mulig nytte og effekt av Diamondcare Keramisk Lakkbeskyttelse kommer vi med noen vasketips:</p>
            </br>

            <ul class="fa-ul">
                <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Etter den første uken står du fritt til å vaske bilen på vanlig måte. Vi anbefaler bilrelaterte vaskeprodukter – ikke Zalo eller parafin/diesel. Før såpevask kan du trygt bruke petrokjemisk avfetting til å fjerne den plagsomme trafikkfilmen som oppstår (spesielt på vinterhalvåret).</li>
                </br>
                <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Vi kommer gjerne med anbefalinger av vaskeprodukter. Dersom du setter bort vasken til andre bør du informere om at du har lakkbeskyttelse på bilen. </li>
                </br>
                <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Ved å benytte Diamondcare Refresher på bilen ca. hver 4-6 mnd. Vil dette gjøre at lakken oppfører seg som da bilen var ny-behandlet. Garantien opprettholdes selv uten bruk av dette produktet. </li>
                </br>
                <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Tørk bilen for å holde den lenger ren. Vi anbefaler at du bruker det medfølgende blå mikrofiber-tørkehåndkleet etter at bilen er ferdig vasker og spylt over. Fukt- og vri det opp før du begynner å tørke. Da tiltrekker det seg mest mulig. </li>
                </br>
                <li><i class="fa-li far fa-gem fa-lg"></i>Rebehandling er ikke nødvendig for å opprettholde garantien, men det kan utføres om ønskelig. Ta kontakt med din forhandler for nærmere informasjon om dette. </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col2">
            <div class="row rad2 h-100 flex-column">
                <div class="col-12 col3">
                    <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
                        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?fbclid=IwAR2KcXLf_v8knVxaJzKdD7WpLzJGrdrqd1pG_kbzB5arEKpRkKPSNvTh9h4&v=HVp1321oon8&feature=youtu.be" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end of col3-->

                <div class="col-12 col4 flex-grow-1">
                    <h4>Har du spørsmål?</h4>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">E-post</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Din e-post">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label" placeholder="Skriv ditt spørsmål her...">Spørsmål</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input class="btn btn-custom" type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end of col4-->

            </div>
            <!--end of rad2-->
        </div>
        <!--end of col2-->
    </div>
    <!--end of rad1-->
</div>
<!--end of container-fluid-->
```